# Is it possible to delete specific entry on Windows event log?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to delete specific windows event-log entry using PowerShell/Any other method.

I have the relevant event using:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -Index 154861
```

My question is if there is a way to delete this entry.

Comment: There is only `Clear-EventLog`, which wipes them all (per log name). For good reasons, discussed here: https://serverfault.com/questions/8339/how-can-i-remove-specific-events-from-the-event-log-in-windows-server-2008 . Even if you went in and mangled the evtx file, it generally breaks the event log indexes. You can export a filtered event log to evtx, and then query that